# Effects of direct and indirect cholinergics on cardiovascular system

Tags: pharmacokinetics, pharmacodynamics

If I give intravenous acetylcholine then the effects produced on cardiovascular system are hypotension , tachycardia and increased cardiac output.
Now if I give intravenous acetylcholine esterase inhibitors on another patient then the effects produced on cardiovascular system are hypertension, bradycardia and decreased cardiac output.
Ach esterase inhibitors also increase acetylcholine concentration then why does the effects are exactly opposite in the above mentioned two cases.

Reference for abovementioned data : Cholinergic drugs ,
katzung pharmacology, 14th edition.

Is it because Ach esterase inhibitors increase Ach concentration locally in the tissues which produce more direct effects while the Ach is rapidly metabolised in the plasma so can't reach into the tissues so it produces more indirect effects via baroreflex ?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. Please take the [tour] and then go through the [help] pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. In particular, this question seems like it might be a better fit for [MedicalSciences.SE], but please do **not** crosspost, instead request migration. However, please note that that site (and this one) expect you to document your prior research (ideally with references to reliable sources). Thanks!

Comment: Okk ,, I added my reference now

Comment: Now can you please explain something about that ? Does the way I m thinking correct ?

Comment: That's a start, but I encourage you to do more than read from a single textbook. In addition, given the poor fit between your question and this site you may wait a long time before someone posts an answer — that is why I recommended you check out what seems to me a more appropriate site ...